# How to check passed type in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If `T` is `string | undefined`, no json parsing need, but return the string itself. How can I implement it?

```js
import { useEffect, useState, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react'

type SetValue<T> = Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>

export default function useLocalStorage<T>(
    key: string,
    fallbackValue: T
): [T, SetValue<T>] {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<T>(() => {
        console.log('key', key)
        if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') {
            const stored = localStorage.getItem(key)
            console.log('stored', stored)
            return stored ? JSON.parse(stored) : fallbackValue // <-- here
        } else {
            return fallbackValue
        }
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined' && value) {
            localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))
        }
    }, [key, value])

    return [value, setValue]
}
```

Comment: ① Please [edit] the title to be more indicative of your question according to [ask]; you don't need to mention TypeScript if the question is tagged as such, and "how to type check" is incredibly vague. ② Does the question depend on react? If so you should tag it as such; if not, you should probably remove it from the example code so that it's a [mre]. ③ What, specifically is your problem?  You say `// <-- here` but there's no indication of what's going wrong; I don't see a compiler error... is it a runtime issue?  What's the difference between your expectation and reality?

Comment: I would not return the parsed object but a pure string, I need a type check for it, I do not know how to make the type check, other languages has `is` operator, is the "type" of the object available for operations in TypeScript?

Comment: Please [edit] the question with this information, and maybe include some example inputs and outputs you expect to see.  It sounds like maybe you're asking for runtime checking of TypeScript types, which is impossible: `T` is erased when TS is compiled to JS.  You can test the type of `fallbackValue` like `return (stored ? (typeof fallbackValue === "string" ? stored : JSON.parse(stored)) : fallbackValue` but I don't know if that meets your needs without specific example use cases.  Ideally a [mre] will have the criteria for acceptance be apparent to others.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isStringOrUndefined<T>(value: T): value is string | undefined {
    return typeof value === 'string' || typeof value === 'undefined'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a type predicate:

```
function isString(value: any): value is string {
    return typeof value === 'string';
}
```

Which we can add to your conditional:

```
return stored ? isString(fallbackValue) ? stored : JSON.parse(stored) : fallbackValue;
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=9&pln=17&pc=95#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMCiAzb6DGMANChgMowCGM6JAIsKmNfgBYlnowXXoCChYBAB2cAL5xsUCCDgByKOkqE5AKFUwAnmHRxOMAGqUANsnQAeACoA%20OAF44DJi1bn9PGgJhDhV69fVsZGFBEThGCihgYQBzAAoANxMzAC44SmFNAEo0pNNdRjhUGCjYxFU4SrhFGGQoUS0dCGw4PLN7Owc5YtKYuQBuVTF1dAAPSFg4ABN0bEpkY3ggkO8wtHQAGQh8EwpoShiLGziKqoBrdE00nuiYolPKueNjACNlM6N8tMtVHLgAbUsHC4nzMfgAuuUqnB8CJigC2rQiiDkuhIQ51h4jtY4nEsvZbAgHtCYXCIMZ0AA6YwQeJyC6aOQkBlZYnQ2HCeHFaDoKb2OA0nbGPZQA7oAD8lMOMAAkjQQHEWWyqhzUOSqTS6dzFFMmUUYDypqySVUanVRNreXBxeFUJFbnEnq93qD0PibZa%20WkAFJkADyADlKcwoBg4p78WknW98B9UYNoWJWcT1jg8IRcfi7ITlZVgC04o10M0BdtdgbRYc4ABCTryYIzbDRXlyOAAMjbrVR%20KJJpNgvL%200OlIwsvlisuJF9gZHJVu%20c0iW7xr7w0TJH%20DJIiPByehZvqCNRJFHrvBQyAA)